# How to fixe vertical spacing in multicell text within table / how to insert multicell text in table?

Tags: tables, spacing, text

```
\documentclass{report}[12pt, oneside, a4paper]
\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{verbose, tmargin=2.5cm, rmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm, lmargin=3.5cm, headsep=0cm}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand{\beginsupplement}{%
    \setcounter{table}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}%
    \setcounter{figure}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}%}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\LARGE}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{textcomp,marvosym}
\usepackage[aboveskip=1pt,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[round]{natbib} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{afterpage}






\begin{document}
\chapter{Materials and Methods}

\begin{longtable}{>{\centering\bfseries}m{3cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.5in} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% Spread rows out...
\caption[M-IV Competence Media Component Solutions]{M-IV Competence Media Component Solutions \label{M-IV}} \\
\toprule
Solution Name & \textbf{Component}  &       \\
\midrule
\endhead
\caption[]{-- Continued from overleaf}\\
\toprule
Solution Name & \textbf{Composition} &      \\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
Solution 21 &    L-Aspartic acid    & 4 g                               \\
            &    L-Glutamic acid    &       0.2 g                   \\
            &    Furmaric acid      &           1.0 g               \\
                &   NaCl                &           4.7 g               \\
            &    K\textsubscript{2}HPO\textsubscript{4} &   0.87 g\\
                &    KH\textsubscript{2}PO\textsubscript{4} &   0.67 g\\
    &    Tween-80 & 0.2 ml\\
    &    Distilled water                            & 850 ml \\
\parbox[\textwidth]{20cm}{\hspace*{2cm} \textnormal{Adjust pH to 7.4 using 4 N NaOH, and then make to 1 L using Distilled water}} \\
                & Sterilise by autoclaving  &               \\
  Solution 22   &    L-Cystine*     &           0.04 g              \\
            &    L-Tyrosine*        &       0.1 g                   \\
        &    L-Citruline        &       0.06 g  \\
                                &    L-Phenylalanine    &       0.2 g   \\
    &    L-Serine           &           0.3 g \\
                        &    L-Alanine          &           0.2 g               \\
        &   Sterilise by filtration     &                       \\
Solution 23     &    CaCl\textsubscript{2}  &               0.1 M       \\
&   Sterilise by autoclaving    &                       \\
&                   &                       \\
Solution 24     &    MgSO\textsubscript{4}  &               0.1 M       \\
        &   Sterilise by autoclave      &                       \\
&                   &                       \\
Solution 40     &    vitamin-free casamino acids &          5\% (w/v)   \\
&   Make to 100 ml with Distilled water     &           \\
&   Sterilise by autoclave                  &           \\
 \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Basically I've tried to insert "Adjust pH to 7.4 using 4 N NaOH, and then make to 1 L using Distilled water" as text that goes across all three rows of my table, however, the row below is really close to the bottom of the text and I was wondering how to get it spaced properly/if there is another way to insert the text. I'm new to LaTeX so I'm still trying to get the hang of everything. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass{report}[12pt, oneside, a4paper]
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{verbose, 
          tmargin=2.5cm, rmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm, lmargin=3.5cm, headsep=0cm}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell,longtable}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\sffamily}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp,marvosym}
\usepackage[aboveskip=1pt,labelfont=bf,
            labelsep=period,
            justification=raggedright,
            singlelinecheck=off]{caption}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Materials and Methods}

\begin{longtable}{l
                  l
                  S[table-format=4.3,table-space-text-post={******}]
                  }
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% Spread rows out...
%\caption{M-IV Competence Media Component Solutions}             \\
%     \label{M-IV}
\toprule
\thead{Solution Name}
            & \thead{Composition}       &  ?                    \\
\midrule
\endhead
    \caption[]{-- Continued from overleaf}                      \\
\toprule
\thead{Solution Name} 
            & \thead{Composition}       &  ?                    \\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
Solution 21 & L-Aspartic acid           & 4 g                   \\
            & L-Glutamic acid           & 0.2 g                 \\
            & Furmaric acid             & 1.0 g                 \\
            & NaCl                      & 4.7 g                 \\
            & K\textsubscript{2}HPO\textsubscript{4} 
                                        & 0.87 g                \\
            & KH\textsubscript{2}PO\textsubscript{4} 
                                        & 0.67 g                \\
            & Tween-80                  & 0.2 ml                \\
            & Distilled water           & 850 ml                \\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{%\makecell[l]{
    Adjust pH to 7.4 using 4 N NaOH,%\\
    and then make to 1 L using Distilled water}                \\
            & Sterilise by autoclaving  &                       \\
Solution 22 & L-Cystine*                & 0.04 g                \\
            & L-Tyrosine*               & 0.1 g                 \\
            & L-Citruline               & 0.06 g                \\
            & L-Phenylalanine           & 0.2 g                 \\
            & L-Serine                  & 0.3 g                 \\
            & L-Alanine                 & 0.2 g                 \\
            & Sterilise by filtration   &                       \\
Solution 23 & CaCl\textsubscript{2}     & 0.1 M                 \\
            & Sterilise by autoclaving  &                       \\
    \addlinespace
Solution 24 & MgSO\textsubscript{4}     & 0.1 M                 \\
            & Sterilise by autoclave    &                       \\
    \addlinespace
Solution 40 & vitamin-free casamino acids 
                                        & 5\,\% (w/v)           \\
            & Make to 100 ml with Distilled water     
                                        &                       \\
            & Sterilise by autoclave    &                       \\         
 \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I omit all packages in your preamble, which aren't relevant for this table, however I add two new: `makecell` from which I use macros `thead` for make column heads more beautiful and prepare possible use of `makecell`, which enables to put long sentence in the middle of table in two lines (if you like to have this). With `S` column type provided by `sinuntx`  I reformat appearance of last table column. I also changes column type of the first two columns  to `l`. This, to may test gives better looking of table.

With this change the table with is narrower from test width, but this is its natural width. If you persist to have wider table, you can replace one `l` column wit adequate width `p` column. The height of table is smaller then text width, so it can be included in text as ordinary table and not as long table (in case, that this is complete table).

Obtained table is:

[image]